# Extend separate lists with the outputs of a function

Tags: python, list

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing the following:

EDIT:

```
def whaa(x):
    # Let's not get too picky about this function
    return list(range(0,x)), list(range(-1,x))

a, b = whaa(10)
c = whaa(20)
a.extend(c[0])
b.extend(c[1])
```

EDIT: The behavior of the function is dependent on the input. And I want the corresponding outputs to go neatly into the same list.

Essentially, what I want to do is access the individual elements of the output tuple and extend my lists without going through the trouble of storing the output into a separate variable. It seems like given this construct, it's not something that's possible but I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for x, y in zip([a, b], c):
    x.extend(y)
```

But then why have you not just left `a` and `b` in a list in the first place?

```
c = whaa(10)
for x, y in zip(c, whaa(20)):
    x.extend(y)
a, b = c                       # save unpacking until the end
```

Comment: Ah! This works! I guess saving unpacking til the end is what I'm missing. Thanks!
I don't understand your question about leaving a and b in a list. They ARE lists, aren't they?

Comment: Doesn't matter what type a and b are. Just that they are related and you want to repeat a similar operation to them, so keep them in a collection. A list is appropriate here, so you have the list of `[a, b]`. Yes they are also lists, so it's nested lists, but the type of `a` and `b` isn't really important - we could be adding ints or updating dicts in the same style.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop to extend each element of the returned tuple:

```
a, b = tuple(x * 2 for x in whaa())

a
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

b
# [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

For the updated question, you can use `zip` as the answer of @John:

```
a, b = tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(whaa(10), whaa(20)))
```

Comment: I think your code will work in the case I have asked about but I didn't account for the fact that this isn't exactly what I was asking. I'll edit the question to reflect what I was really after! Sorry about that!